# Adjust HorizontalScrollView height based on childs' height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` in which I programmatically add childs. The scroll view is pretty simple:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/child_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

As said, in `child_container` I have to programmatically add child views. Child views are all inflated from this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/content_padding"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the text in the TextView can be small (2 lines) or larger, up to 7-8 lines. How can I have this `HorizontalScrollView` to adapt its height based on the text?

In XML, I could just set `android:lines="10"` to the text view, but the actual maximum number of lines might change and I can't hardcode that value.

I tried lots of stuff at runtime, like requesting layouts and re-measuring, but I might be doing it wrong. Thank you.

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_container);
for (String text : texts) {

    View childView = inflater.inflate(...);
    TextView textView = childView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    textView.setText(text);

    l.addView(childView);
}
// Here do something on l 
// (or on its parent, the HorizontalScrollView)
// to change its height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing. Here's my outer layout:

```
<com.app.WrapContentHorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.app.WrapContentHorizontalScrollView>
```

Here's my child layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp" />

    <TextView
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my class:

```
public class WrapContentHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private LinearLayout directChild;
    private int targetHeight;
    private final static int UNSPECIFIED = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

    public WrapContentHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public WrapContentHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public WrapContentHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        directChild = new LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        super.addView(directChild);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(@NonNull View child) {
        if (directChild != null) {
            directChild.addView(child);
            child.measure(UNSPECIFIED, UNSPECIFIED);
            targetHeight = Math.max(targetHeight, child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int newHeight = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(targetHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, newHeight);
    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Set your linear layout height to wrap_content.

Comment: You mean the child LinearLayout ? It does not work, I still see only one line of text.

Comment: Is your problem that your text is not multilining or that the child height and parent height are wrong? You are not being clear in your question. Try setting the minLine to 1 in the xml.

Comment: I just can't see lines 2-3-4-5-.. . My feeling is that when measuring, the HorizontalScrollView counts just 1 line for the TextViews. If I hardcode the number of values with android:numLines, it is reflected in the final height. But I want height to be based on text length, not a predefined value.

Comment: If I set minLines=3, I see 3 lines; if I set minLines=5, I see 5 lines. But there are more..

Comment: Try removing anything about lines in your xml, see if letting it take care of itself does it.